# basic php test in magento using module class, driving me crazy!

Tags: magento2, php-7

I have the following class on my root magento2 directory: 
test();

PHP storm can link to the MagentoU\test class, so the path is correct and the class exists, but I get the following error when I ran the file in the browser or in the command line I get the following: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Training\Unit2\MagentoU\test' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\Unit1_162test.php on line 3

So it looks like phpStorm finds the class but magento/php dont?

I'm using magento EE 2.1 in an XAMPP installation

I have tried to add a '\' at the beginning of the use statement and to call directly to the class as 'new Training\Unit2\MagentoU\test', same results.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that the created class/files have at least the same level of access to the Magento files/folders as the rest. A lot of times, when everything seems to be correct but a module still doesn't work, it usually means there's something wrong with the actual permissions/ownership of the files.

Comment: Thanks, I checked it and it has the same permissions as other files...completely lost with this....

Comment: I think that this is just not possible in Magento, ie refer to a module class from the Magento root directory.